# Injecting dependencies in tests

Tags: php, symfony

I am relatively new to symfony. Now I wrote a library, a little decorator class what I wold like to test.

The class called `MessageHtmlDecorator->decorateByKey` waiting for a `MessageManage` object. `MessageManage` needs a `Logger` class injected. And this is a simple case.

These classes are **not services**, just simple utils/libraries!

So I like to create a test like this:

```
public function testDecorateByKey()
{
    $messageManage = new MessageManage();
    $htmlMessageDecorate = new HtmlMessageDecorate();
    $this->assertEquals('<p>First error message</p>', $htmlMessageDecorate->decorateByKey($messageManage, 'error'));
}
```

`MessageManage` constructor:

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

How can I do that `MessageManage` automatically injected with logger?

So what I want to achieve is let dependency injection be same as in the symfony project.

I tried to search on symfony pages without success.

If something not clear, please comment me, I will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit provides builtin mocking, I doubt that Symfony will be able to auto inject mocks for your test as it has no idea what the assertions should be.

```
$mockLogger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
$mockLogger->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method("error")
    ->with("An error occurred");
$messageManage = new MessageManage($mockLogger);
```